# Uniform Texture Mapping Blender

Tags: texturing, uv

I want my texture to be applied uniformely to my Blender model, but currently, when I apply my texture, it gets scaled depending on the size of each triangle and its vertices, but that's not what I'm looking for,

This is the result:

[image: Result]

This is the texture:

[image: Texture]

This is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into using a [UV map](http://blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/mapping/uv.html)?

Comment: What unwrapping method did you use in Blender to get that result?

Comment: I actually just create a material with a texture and applied it to the model, U did not UV unwrap anyhting

Comment: @Whiteclaws Select the geometry first. Go to edit mode (Tab), select the geometry (A), press U for unwrap.